# How to continue hierarchy of bullets in new slide?

Tags: itemize, enumitem, presentations

I have some hierarchy in one slide that i want to keep in the follow slide. How i can do that?

Code example:

```
\documentclass[ps,clariphy]{prosper} %% clariphy it's the company where I work. I Think it's an environment
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{ Slide 1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
         \begin{itemize}
             \item Item A
         \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}{ Slide 2}
    \begin{itemize}   %%Same hierarchy of "Item A"
       \item Item B
    \end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

I want "Item B" of Slide 2 with the same hierarchy of "Item A" on Slide 1 (green color).

Comment: How is `slide` defined? Please give us a complete example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Are you using the standard `slides` class? (I can't remember if that has a `slide` environment - haven't used it for years - so this is just a guess.)

Comment: Could be `pdfscreen`?

Comment: @cfr I think it's [`powerdot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/powerdot).

Comment: Instead of using two different slides I think it's better to use overlays.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why especially? `pdfscreen` has a `slide` environment, too. I'm not querying you - I just wondered what the characteristic features are of powerdot vs pdfscreen.

Comment: @cfr I added type of document

Comment: Why don't you just do `\begin{itemize}\begin{itemize}` in slide 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Obviously I had to remove the custom style.

```
\documentclass[ps]{prosper} %% clariphy it's the company where I work. I Think it's an environment
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{ Slide 1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
         \begin{itemize}
             \item Item A
         \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}{ Slide 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \phantom{Item 1}
    \begin{itemize}   %%Same hierarchy of "Item A"
       \item Item B
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

The way to continue hierarchy on another slide is setting an "empty" bullet. It's not the better way to do this. But it works for me:

Code example solved:

```
\documentclass[ps,clariphy]{prosper} %% clariphy it's the company where I work. I Think it's an environment
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{ Slide 1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
         \begin{itemize}
             \item Item A
         \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}{ Slide 2}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[ ]              %% Empty bullet to solve hierarchy problem
        \begin{itemize}   %%Same hierarchy of "Item A"
            \item Item B
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```